# Interpreting main effects in the presence of interaction effects in regression

Tags: regression

I have always been confused about interpreting main effects in the presence of interaction effects.

Put simply,

Y = a sense of belonging to school

X1 = ethnicity (0= white, 1=black) / negative effect

X2 = relationship with teachers (1= very bad ~ 4 very good) / negative effect

X1*X2 = interaction term / positive effect

In this case,
Should I say,

Black students have a lower sense of belonging to school than white students do. **The students' relationship with teachers is negatively associated with their sense of belonging to school**. However, black students have a higher sense of belonging to school when they have good relationships with teachers.

Or,

Black students have a lower sense of belonging to school than white students do. However, black students have a higher sense of belonging to school when they have good relationships with teachers **even after controlling the main effect of the relationship with teachers on their sense of belonging to school.**

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

**In the presence of an interaction, you should not interpret the main effects.** What the estimated effect of $x_2$ is, depends on $x_1$, and vice versa. This is how you specified the model, after all.

In your example, the negative association between $x_2$ and $y$ you've observed is the effect for the reference group: $x_1 = 0$ (white). The fact that the interaction's effect is positive tells you that if $x_1 = 1$ (black) *and* $x_2$ is high (better relationship with teachers), then $y$ (sense of belonging) increases, compared to the reference group. In fact, if the effect size of the interaction is large enough, **it might even be that there is a negative association between $x_2$ and $y$ for white students, while there is a positive effect for $x_2$ and $y$ for black students.**

On a different note, from reading your question I assume $y$ and $x_2$ both are self-reported values. In that case it would be slightly more correct to say that (given $x_1 = 0$) students who *claim* to have a better relationship with their teachers report a weaker sense of belonging to the school. I would also be careful to check whether the groups are otherwise homogeneous before attributing the observed differences to race (e.g. is there a similar ratio of men/women, are the groups similarly aged, etc.).